# bash while loops not structured correctly

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I have three different user inputs I need to confirm and I'm doing so via "Is this right: Yes or No" while loops.  Obviously my code is wrong because although the first loop executes correctly, my script that just tests these loops finishes before executing the other two loops.  See code below.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
#loop 1
while [ "$answer" != "Yes" ]
do
stuff
read answer
done

#loop 2
while [ "$answer" != "Yes" ]
do
stuff
read answer
done

#loop 3
while [ "$answer" != "Yes" ]
do
stuff
read answer
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first loop ends when `$answer` contains `Yes`. Then the second loop immediately performs the same test, the test fails, so the loop ends immediately. The same thing happens with the third loop.

You should clear `$answer` between the loops:

```
#loop 1
while [ "$answer" != "Yes" ]
do
stuff
read answer
done

answer=

#loop 2
while [ "$answer" != "Yes" ]
do
stuff
read answer
done

answer=

#loop 3
while [ "$answer" != "Yes" ]
do
stuff
read answer
done
```

Comment: You can clear answer 2 ways, either `answer=` as above, or with `unset answer` as well. Both do the same thing, it is simply a preference issue.

Comment: @David C. Rankin - utilizing the unset keyword seems like better engineering.

Comment: Either way is fine. 1/2 the manuals explain it with `var=` the other 1/2 use `unset var`. One way to avoid this `answer=yes` issue is to write a `testyn()` function that preforms the test. That way all variables are local to the test function and cannot effect the remainder of your script.

Comment: @Barmar, David C. Rankin - mmm...no, adding unset answer between my loops does not work within my script that simply tests these loops.  Maybe I should clarify: I want loop 1 to run until Yes.  Loop 2 to run until Yes.  Loop 3 to run until Yes.  As it stands, as soon as Loop 1 receives Yes, runtime ends.

Comment: @David C. Rankin - I will do that, but first I need to no why my script stops at first Yes.

Comment: Please provide a working version of your test case. I'll write one as well. Something else is going on that isn't shown in your original question.

Comment: @David C Rankin - Ooooh sh***t...I had a spelling mistake.  Infinite apologies including all different known sizes of infinity.  Proceeding with functioning to modify var scope as you suggested...

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)  I added an answer with an example of a `function testyn`. Use it for what it's worth. Have a good night.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a more structured approach with functions (more DRY)

```
until_yes () {
    local stuff=$1
    local answer
    until [[ ${answer,,} == yes ]]; do
        $stuff
        read -p "Is this correct? (yes/no) " answer
    done
}

stuff1 () { ... }
stuff2 () { ... }
stuff3 () { ... }

until_yes stuff1
until_yes stuff2
until_yes stuff3
```

Comment: Although the answer above and below initially allowed me to hack my way through finishing the script I was writing, your code is clearly the most succinct and structured.  You did not, however, answer my question, which was WHY the code portion I posted was not working, as opposed to HOW BEST to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Given our discussions in the comments, here is a quick example of `unset` and `var=` along with a `function tesyn` that shows the different uses that can be made of a test when responding to user input. The function returns `0` (bash true) on `yes` and `1` (bash false) on `no` allowing simple test constructs after a question.

```
#!/bin/bash

function testyn {
    local answer
    read answer
    while : ; do
        answer=$(tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' <<<$answer)     # translate answer to lower-case
        case "$answer" in

            yes ) 
                return 0
                ;;
            no  ) 
                return 1
                ;;
            *   )
                printf "    Invalid Input, Enter (yes/no): "
                read answer
                ;;
        esac
    done
}

printf "Continue? (yes/no): " 
while read answer && [ "$answer" != yes ]; do
    printf "  Invalid input, (yes/no): "
done

unset answer

printf "Continue? (yes/no): " 
while read answer && [ "$answer" != yes ]; do
    printf "  Invalid input, (yes/no): "
done

answer=

printf "Continue? (yes/no): " 
while read answer && [ "$answer" != yes ]; do
    printf "  Invalid input, (yes/no): "
done

## call function tesyn after a question, then
#  use any test that tests for 1 or 0 to
#  respond to the answer
printf "\n  Would you like to continue? (y/n): "
testyn || {
    printf "\nanswer was no, exiting...\n\n"
    exit 1
}

printf "\nAnswer must have been 'yes'. All Done!\n\n"

exit 0
```

**Use/output:**

```
$ bash testyn.sh
Continue? (yes/no): maybe
  Invalid input, (yes/no): yes
Continue? (yes/no): really
  Invalid input, (yes/no): yes
Continue? (yes/no): yes

Would you like to continue? (y/n): of_course
  Invalid Input, Enter (yes/no): ok
  Invalid Input, Enter (yes/no): yes

Answer must have been 'yes'. All Done!
```

Comment: Your tests all fail if `read` itself fails: try, when prompted for yes/no, to enter an EOF (Ctrl-D) and enjoy your beautiful bug.

Comment: The purpose was not to trap EOF. You can push `ctrl+d` all day long, and all it will do to the test is reprint the prompt line. Enter (yes/no) and it works as it should, enter anything else, and you are prompted again. I'm sure your sarcasm is in direct proportion to both your age and maturity. It's not needed or welcomed. Let's compare to your answer.

Comment: The purpose is to be sure that the user _really_ wants to continue. As in _do you really want to erase the file?_ Now try it on your own:  `printf "Continue? (yes/no): "; while read answer && [ "$answer" != yes ]; do printf "  Invalid input, (yes/no): "; done; echo "You typed yes"`. Type an EOF when prompt, and you'll see that `You typed yes` will be echoed, and the program will continue happily. Well, as a user, I'm not expecting this from a program. Now if this is the behavior you want, you should clearly mention it, as in my book this is a dangerous behavior.